# Python multiprocessing performance issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here's my approximate flow of project

1. save python custom class to pickle file
2. load pickle file which in multiprocess
3. using loaded pickle file input into Machine Learning model

---

**My Code**

```py
def get_learning_data(file):
    print(file)
    picklefile = open(file, 'rb')
    processed_data = pickle.load(picklefile)
    picklefile.close()
    print(f'end with file {file}')
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # files 
    file_list = [r'sample{0}.pickle'.format(i) for i in range(100)]
    _start = time()
    file_count = len(file_list)
    print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    MAX_PROCESS = 12
    d = file_count // MAX_PROCESS if file_count % MAX_PROCESS == 0 else file_count // MAX_PROCESS +1
    file_batch = [file_list[i * MAX_PROCESS : (i + 1) * MAX_PROCESS] for i in range(d)]
    
    with multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESS) as pool:
        for files in file_batch:
            pool.map(
                get_learning_data,
                files
            )
    print(f'multi done time : {time() - _start}')

    _start = time()
    for f in file_list:
        get_learning_data(f)
    print(f'single done time : {time() - _start}')
```

#### Problems

1. When `print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` cpu count equals 20, which i thought it was the count of cpu's core, but it matches with processer count..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juBCG.png)

if i want to optimize max process, which should it be proper 12? 20?

2. In my research because of python's GIL issue, i've used multiprocessing. if there's any alternative solution please recommend me
3. testing with 100 files, using 10 processes the multi processing time took 67 sec, single took me 183 sec. I can understand context switching takes some time but the difference between 183 and 67 is too small.
   My colleague tested with 30 core cpu, the result of 30 core took more time than single core which i can't understand why
4. is there a way to save python dataclass as file excluding the way of xml, pickle, and json

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to inspect what is the bottleneck, your use-case (the powerful CPU) it is usually the disk, it maybe RAM bandwidth, it maybe PCIe (GPU) too.

Secondly, in your example the file needed to load may be cached so the `single done time` maybe faster

Suggestion: try to save file to RAM and re-run the benchmark with it

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was wondering how to inspect bottleneck in local enviornment.. and i've tested with different condision and got same result which stands the files were not cached.. finally additional question is there a way to save python dataclass as file excluding xml, pickle, and json. thanks Chicky

Answer (score 0):

The `multiprocessing` module is good for speeding up applications that are *CPU-bound*. That is, their performance is limited by how fast you can process instructions.

In your worker function the only thing you are doing is reading from disk.
The problem is, reading from disk is generally a lot slower than processing instructions. Especially if you have multiple workers reading different files (from the same disk) at the same time. All those open and write requests go through the single I/O subsystem in the OS. So you will quickly reach a point where either the disk or the I/O subsystem are saturated and cannot go any faster.

Such an application is described as *I/O-bound*.
Using `multiprocessing` on an I/O-bound application generally doesn't help much, as you are experiencing.

### What can be done?

If you are using a HDD, moving to a RAM-disk or SSD might help. This does not circumvent the limitation of the I/O subsystem though.

Given your numbers, I would re-run the test with the `Pool` limited to different amount of workers in the range 2-6 and see which number of workers offers the best performance for I/O.

Assuming you are also going `multiprocessing` to run the training, you want to use the maximum amount of processors. In that case you could use a shared `Value` to indicate how many processes are in the process of reading a file. If that number is higher than the number you learned in the previously mentioned test, the worker should `sleep` for a time and try again. Every worker increases the `Value` by one before it opens the file, and decrease it by one after it has finished reading.

**Edit1**

In your comment you talk about `s3` and how that would influence things. One thing to remember is that *there is no "cloud"*. It's just other people's computers reached by network.

That is one system that we didn't cover yet: network I/O.
And here the bad news is that it's *usually slower* than disk I/O.

Sometimes I use `nc`(netcat) to transfer files from computer to computer over a point-to-point gigabit (1000 Mbit/s) ethernet link. With consumer equipment that is currently the best case possible. In that situation I get a max troughput of about 120 MB/s. With some TCP overhead that means that this point-to-point connection is close to saturated.

So the question is, how fast is the network connection between the machine storing the data and the machine running the computation? Unless both are in the same room or the same data-center, I would guess a lot less than a gigabit/s. In which case it won't improve your speed.

Comment: thank you Smith, i never thought about I/O subsystem.. at the actual application, the files would be stored in s3 and will use multiprocess getting files. in this case would I/O subsystem matter?

Comment: @딩스터 See Edit1.